# PHP Laravel - How to dynamically connect Via SSH to a MySQL database

Tags: php, laravel

Currently I have the ability to connect to either a mysql or postgres database dynamically through a job, execute a select statement then export to an excel spreadsheet:

```
  DB::purge("$connectionName");

    if($Driver == "mysql"){
        $charset = "utf8mb4";
    } else if($Driver == "pgsql"){
        $charset = "utf8";
    } else{
        $charset = "";
    }

    Config::set("database.connections.$connectionName", [
        "driver" => "$Driver",
        "port" => "$Port",
        "host" => "$Host",
        "database" => "$DBName",
        "username" => "$UserName",
        "password" => "$Password",
        'charset' => "$charset"
    ]);

    $query = DB::connection("$connectionName")->select($statement);
    $q_raw = $query;

    $rowCount = count($query);

    $query= json_decode( json_encode($query), true);

    $filename_e = $filename.'-'.$range.'-^^-'.$mytime;


    if($rowCount == 0){

        $pdo = DB::connection($connectionName)->getPdo();
        $select = $pdo->query($statement);

        $colcount = $select->columnCount();

        $meta = $select->getColumnMeta(0);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $colcount; ++$i) {
            $query[] = $select->getColumnMeta($i)['name'];
        }


    }

    Excel::create($filename_e, function($excel) use ($query, $filename) {

        $excel->sheet($filename, function($sheet) use ($query){
            $sheet->fromArray($query);
        });

    })->store('xls', storage_path('excel/exports'));

    $filepath = storage_path('excel/exports').'/'.$filename_e.'.xls';
```

I need the ability to do exactly this however but via a SSH connection to a MySQL server using an uploaded SSH key etc.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options. One is simple create an ssh tunnel on the server where PHP is installed, and update your Laravel config settings.
You can find an example here http://quintagroup.com/services/support/tutorials/mysql-linux

Another options is too use a laravel package like https://github.com/stechstudio/laravel-ssh-tunnel that does this for you.

Comment: The problem with the first option is that it is static, you have to manually create a new tunnel for each MySQL database. My whole system is dynamic and can take any database details from the storage. I cant manually create a tunnel for each one. The second option looks more promising and I'll look into it. Thanks.